# I have a THREE.js visualizer setup that reacts to an audio file. How do I make it react to the audio of text-to-speech engine?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have both of the modules setup i.e. The visualizer reacts to an audio file being played and the text-to-speech engine speaks perfectly. I am having issue with interfacing both of them such that the visualizer reacts when the engine speaks. Here's my code.

```
import { AudioListener, Audio, AudioLoader, AudioAnalyser, Clock } from 'three';
import { Scene, SphereGeometry, Vector3, PerspectiveCamera, WebGLRenderer, Color, MeshBasicMaterial, MeshStandardMaterial, Mesh } from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.146/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
import { createSculptureWithGeometry } from 'https://unpkg.com/shader-park-core/dist/shader-park-core.esm.js';

let scene = new Scene();

let camera = new PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 1.5;

let renderer = new WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, transparent: true });
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setClearColor(new Color(1, 1, 1), 0);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


let clock = new Clock();

// AUDIO
// create an AudioListener and add it to the camera
const listener = new AudioListener();
camera.add(listener);

// create an Audio source
const sound = new Audio(listener);

let button = document.querySelector('.button');
button.innerHTML = "Loading Audio..."

// load a sound and set it as the Audio object's buffer
const audioLoader = new AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load('https://cdn.glitch.global/59b80ec2-4e5b-4b54-b910-f3441cac0fd6/OP1Beat.wav?v=1667175863547', function (buffer) {
    sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    sound.setLoop(true);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    button.innerHTML = "Play Audio"
    button.addEventListener('pointerdown', () => {
        sound.play();
        button.style.display = 'none';
    }, false);
});


// create an AudioAnalyser, passing in the sound and desired fftSize
// get the average frequency of the sound



const analyser = new AudioAnalyser(sound, 32);


let state = {
    mouse: new Vector3(),
    currMouse: new Vector3(),
    pointerDown: 0.0,
    currPointerDown: 0.0,
    audio: 0.0,
    currAudio: 0.0,
    time: 0.0
}

window.addEventListener('pointermove', (event) => {
    state.currMouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    state.currMouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}, false);

window.addEventListener('pointerdown', (event) => state.currPointerDown = 1.0, false);
window.addEventListener('pointerup', (event) => state.currPointerDown = 0.0, false);


let geometry = new SphereGeometry(2, 45, 45);

export function spCode() {
    return `
        let audio = input();
        let pointerDown = input();


        setMaxIterations(5);
        let s = getSpace();
        let r = getRayDirection();

        let n1 = noise(r * 4 +vec3(0, audio, vec3(0, audio, audio))*.5 );
        let n = noise(s + vec3(0, 0, audio+time*.1) + n1);

        metal(n*.5+.5);
        shine(n*.5+.5);

        color(normal * .1 + vec3(19, 0, 0));
        boxFrame(vec3(2), abs(n) * .1 + .04 );
        mixGeo(0);
        sphere(n * .5 + .8);
    `;
}


// // // Create Shader Park Sculpture
let mesh = createSculptureWithGeometry(geometry, spCode(), () => ({
    time: state.time,
    pointerDown: state.pointerDown,
    audio: state.audio,
    mouse: state.mouse,
    _scale: .5
}));

scene.add(mesh);
// Add Controlls
// let controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement, {
//     enableDamping: false,
//     dampingFactor: 0,
//     zoomSpeed: 0,
//     rotateSpeed: 0
// });

let onWindowResize = () => {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize);

let render = () => {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    state.time += clock.getDelta();
    // controls.update();
    if (analyser) {
        state.currAudio += Math.pow((analyser.getFrequencyData()[0] / 255) * .75, 9) + clock.getDelta() * .5;
        state.audio = .2 * state.currAudio + .8 * state.audio;
    }
    // state.pointerDown = .1 * state.currPointerDown + .9 * state.pointerDown;
    // state.mouse.lerp(state.currMouse, .05);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();


function getVoices() {
    let voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    if (!voices.length) {
        // some time the voice will not be initialized so we can call spaek with empty string
        // this will initialize the voices 
        let utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("");
        speechSynthesis.speak(utterance);
        voices = speechSynthesis.getVoices();
    }
    return voices;
}
let voices = getVoices();

function speak(text, visualizer) {
    // create a SpeechSynthesisUtterance to configure the how text to be spoken 
    let speakData = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    speakData.volume = 0.5; // From 0 to 1
    speakData.rate = 0.8; // From 0.1 to 10
    speakData.pitch = 0; // From 0 to 2
    speakData.text = text;
    speakData.lang = 'en';
    speakData.voice = voices[0];

    // attach event handlers to update the visualizer
    speakData.onstart = function () {

    };

    speakData.onpause = function () {

    };

    speakData.onresume = function () {

    };

    speakData.onend = function () {

    };

    // pass the SpeechSynthesisUtterance to speechSynthesis.speak to start speaking 
    speechSynthesis.speak(speakData);
}


if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {


    let rate = 1, pitch = 2, volume = 1;
    let text = "Spaecking with volume = 1 rate =1 pitch =2 ";

    speak(text);

    // setTimeout(() => { // speak after 2 seconds 
    //     rate = 0.5; pitch = 1.5, volume = 0.5;
    //     text = "Spaecking with volume = 0.5 rate = 0.5 pitch = 1.5 ";
    //     speak(text);
    // }, 2000);
} else {
    console.log(' Speech Synthesis Not Supported ');
}
```

I asked Chat-GPT for some help and it suggested generating audio array from the engine's voice and passing it to the mesh. That didn't work. I switched to Python backend for the TTS(text-to-speech) and tried passing the system's audio as an array via sockets. That ended up with the browser lagging.
Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.